# Cut off string after a certain length

Tags: python, string

I wrote this code:

```
name = 'Programmstrukturen 2'
num1=5
num2='$'
lang_name=len(name)

m_res=lang_name % num1

for x in range(num1):
    print 'x =' + str(x)
    print 'num1='+str(x)
    print name[x] + name[x+num1] + name[x+num1+num1] + name[x+num1+num1+num1]
```

What it does is pretty easy, it just prints i+4 + i+4+4 + i+4+4+4 chars for the amount of num1.
It is working , but is there any chance to improve the loop by reducing the last line ? And put the outputs together into one?

Current output:

```
x =0
num1 =0
Parr
x =1
num1 =1
rmue
x =2
num1 =2
omkn
x =3
num1 =3
gst
x =4
num1 =4
rtu2
```

Wished output:

```
Parrrmueomkngst rtu2
```

Can this be done by += or .join ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name = 'Programmstrukturen 2'
num1=5
output=''
for x in range(num1):
    for i in range(num1-1):
        output+=name[x+num1*i]    #you could simplify the long line like this

print output
```

---

```
>>> 
Parrrmueomkngst rtu2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `.join`:

```
name = 'Programmstrukturen 2'
num1 = 5
output = ''.join(name[x::num1] for x in range(num1))
```